# Combination of two lists in python

Tags: python, list

I went through some questions on combining two lists with itertools but I could not find one that solves my problem. So, would it be possible to do the following with itertools (or any other module) in python?
I have two list:

```
list1 = ['Elizabeth', 'Anne', 'Wells', 'Cannon']
list2 = ['E.', 'A.', 'W.', 'C.']
```

Now, I'm looking for a solution to combine them such as the result looks like the following (e.g., as a list of list):

```
['Elizabeth', 'Anne', 'Wells', 'Cannon']
['E.', 'Anne', 'Wells', 'Cannon']
['Elizabeth', 'A.', 'Wells', 'Cannon']
['Elizabeth', 'Anne', 'W.', 'Cannon']
['Elizabeth', 'Anne', 'Wells', 'C.']
['E.', 'A.', 'Wells', 'Cannon']
['E.', 'Anne', 'W.', 'Cannon']
...
['E.', 'A.', 'W.', 'C.']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, show some of the codes you attempted to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Produce longer and longer combinations of *indices*, then use those to replace names with initials:

```
from itertools import combinations

def replacements(names, initials):
    for count in range(len(names)):
        for positions in combinations(range(len(names)), count):
            yield [initials[i] if i in positions else name for i, name in enumerate(names)]
    yield initials
```

So the above first doesn't replace anything (`length = 0`), then replaces *one* element (`length = 1`, outputing `[0]`, then `[1]`, etc.), all the way up to 3 replacements (`[0, 1, 2]`, `[0, 1, 3]`, etc.). Finally, we output `initials`, as the "4 replacements" case.

Demo:

```
>>> names = ['Elizabeth', 'Anne', 'Wells', 'Cannon']
>>> initials = ['E.', 'A.', 'W.', 'C.']
>>> for result in replacements(names, initials):
...     print(result)
...
['Elizabeth', 'Anne', 'Wells', 'Cannon']
['E.', 'Anne', 'Wells', 'Cannon']
['Elizabeth', 'A.', 'Wells', 'Cannon']
['Elizabeth', 'Anne', 'W.', 'Cannon']
['Elizabeth', 'Anne', 'Wells', 'C.']
['E.', 'A.', 'Wells', 'Cannon']
['E.', 'Anne', 'W.', 'Cannon']
['E.', 'Anne', 'Wells', 'C.']
['Elizabeth', 'A.', 'W.', 'Cannon']
['Elizabeth', 'A.', 'Wells', 'C.']
['Elizabeth', 'Anne', 'W.', 'C.']
['E.', 'A.', 'W.', 'Cannon']
['E.', 'A.', 'Wells', 'C.']
['E.', 'Anne', 'W.', 'C.']
['Elizabeth', 'A.', 'W.', 'C.']
['E.', 'A.', 'W.', 'C.']
```

Of course, instead of using a dedicated `initials` list, you could just use `name[0] + '.'` each time to just generate the initial.